# AEM 6.1 Touch UI allows submit when text field is set to required

Tags: touch, adobe, aem

For accessibility purposes, I have a component with an alt textfield in Touch UI dialog that has `required="true"`.
However, an author is allowed to hit submit without actually having anything in the field. Also, it's not validating before hand - the author can't see that this field is required until they type something and delete it out of the field; only then can they see that the field is "required.

How can I get this alt text field required so that an author needs to enter in some text before submitting it for the component?

Thanks for any direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the documentation https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/granite-ui/api/jcr_root/libs/granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield/index.html, you need to set the property "required" (type boolean) to "true" to achieve this. I have tested on AEM 6.1 SP1 and works fine.

Anyway if you are looking for something "before submiting" or "on dialog ready" states then you will need Javascript. You will need to create a clientlib folder under components with categories `cq.authoring.dialog`.

Please take a look to this that would solve the problem if that is the case:
http://experience-aem.blogspot.in/2015/02/aem-6-sp2-touch-ui-dialog-before-submit.html

Comment: Thanks for the post back :) I'm able to get a notification, however the dialog closes even when the notification appears. For example, I go an hit the configure button for my component. Then try and submit without anything in the required field. The error message appears but the dialog closes. Sometimes I'll get another message to e appear saying Server Error. Any ideas?

Comment: I will suggest to debug the code to find what is going on, remember this: `e.stopPropagation();` and `e.preventDefault();` stop submitting the form and ` $form.submit();` submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `required="true"` is not valid. You either need to just add the `required` attribute without any value or you can add it as `required="required"`.

For e.g.,

```
<input type="text" required>
<input type="text" required="required">
```